# How to install pygbif on python 3.7?

Tags: version, python-3.7

I've got problem with installing pygbif library on my Windows 10. I'm using Python 3.7. Did anyone install with success?

Comment: What, specifically, is the problem? We already know you have a problem, or you wouldn't have posted here. Is there any error message? What happens when you try? How did you try to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to have a similar problem and

`pip install requests-cache == 0.7.4`

in cmd helped me, but it totally depends on the error you get.

My suggestion is just a blind shot, but I hope it helps.